# how to use Laravel Rinvex Attributes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, attributes

I'm trying to use https://github.com/rinvex/attributes, and can't understand how.
Docs are not clear for me and i need help.

After installing the package i've done next:

I have \App\Models\Product class that i want to make attributable.
So I put in model

```
use Rinvex\Attributes\Traits\Attributable;

class Product extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use Sluggable;
    use Attributable;

/***/
```

In AppServiceProvider's boot():

```
app('rinvex.attributes.entities')->push(App\Models\Product::class);
```

Next - just like in docs - creating the attribute in Tinker console just like that:

```
app('rinvex.attributes.attribute')->create([
    'slug' => 'size',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'name' => 'Product Size',
    'entities' => ['App\Models\Product'],
]);
```

In DB i see added entries in attributes_entries and attributes tables.

But when i try to call

```
$product->size = 50;
$product->save(); - got "not found field in Model".
```

What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you register **varchar** type? As it mentioned in documentation, 
**Rinvex Attributes does NOT register any types by default** (see https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-attributes#register-your-types)

So i suggest you to add this code in your service providers register method:

```
    Attribute::typeMap([
        'varchar' => \Rinvex\Attributes\Models\Type\Varchar::class,
    ]);
```

Don't forget to include this class

```
use Rinvex\Attributes\Models\Attribute
```